# How do you center a title for a diagram output to SVG using dot?

Tags: graphviz

So far I tried this line but dot keeps pushing it aside making room for my nodes (pushes it to the right):

```
_diagram_info [shape="plaintext", label="My Diagram\l", fontsize=13]
```

Is there a way to center the label by pos, using dot?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

That's how I'd add a title for a graph:

```
digraph {
    // nodes, edges, subgraphs 
    ...
    // title
    labelloc="t";
    label="My Diagram";
}
```

This will add a centered title to the top of the graph.

The same syntax can also be used for subgraphs.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell us where is this documented?

Comment: Note that you maybe need to [prefix a subgraph's name with "cluster"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586857/344480) to show its `label`.

Comment: @WillSheppard, I find it in https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelloc and https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:label