# Graphviz subgraph doesn't get visualized

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to create a graph with two subgraphs in dot. The code is as follows:

```
digraph G {
        subgraph step1 {
                style=filled;
                node [label="Compiler"] step1_Compiler;
                node [label="Maschine"] step1_Maschine;
                color=lightgrey;
        }

        subgraph step2 {
                style=filled;
                color=lightgrey;
                node [label="Interpretierer"] step2_Interpretierer;
                node [label="Maschine"] step2_Maschine;
                label="Virtuelle Maschine";
        }

        "Programm (Java)" -> step1_Compiler;
        step1_Compiler -> step1_Maschine;
        step1_Maschine -> "Bytecode";
        "Bytecode" -> step2_Interpretierer;
        step2_Interpretierer -> step2_Maschine;
        step2_Maschine -> "Ergebnis";
}
```

The result I am getting looks like the following:

[image: Result of above code]

I expected to see a box around both subgraphs. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You'll have to prefix the name of your subgraphs with *cluster*:

```
subgraph clusterstep1 {
```

and

```
subgraph clusterstep2 {
```

in order to get the style and label.

From the [graphiz documentation, section "Subgraphs and Clusters"](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language):

> The third role for subgraphs directly involves how the graph will be
>   laid out by certain layout engines. **If the name of the subgraph begins
>   with cluster, Graphviz notes the subgraph as a special cluster
>   subgraph**. If supported, the layout engine will do the layout so that
>   the nodes belonging to the cluster are drawn together, with the entire
>   drawing of the cluster contained within a bounding rectangle. Note
>   that, for good and bad, cluster subgraphs are not part of the DOT
>   language, but solely a syntactic convention adhered to by certain of
>   the layout engines.

Comment: So will subgraph and subgraph cluster* both result in a visual grouping under the layout algorithms?

Comment: Prefixing the name with `cluster` is such a stupid design choice... Why isn's keyword `subgraph` enough???

Comment: @71GA: You are absolutely right, but why ask this here? File a bug against graphviz.

Comment: @71GA: Filed it myself... https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2187

Comment: Thank you for this! I had a file with two subgraphs, one of which *happened to be called* `cluster` and I couldn't figure out why only one of them was visible ...