# Unable to get subgraphs drawn

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph G {
    compound=true;

    subgraph SJC {
        node [style="filled"];  
        label = "SJC";
        channel [shape=cylinder];

    }
    subgraph Fleet {
        node [style="filled"];
        App1 [shape=cylinder];
        App2 [shape=cylinder];
        App3 [shape=cylinder];
        label = "Fleet of machines";
        style="filled";
        color="lightgrey";

    }

    App1 -> channel [ltail=SJC, lhead=Fleet];

}
```

With the above code, my expectation is to get 2 container boxes corresponding to the subgraph. However, I am getting the image as follows:

[image]

Also, I am getting two warnings.

```
Warning: cluster named Fleet not found
Warning: cluster named SJC not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your corrected code:

```
digraph G {
compound=true;

subgraph cluster_SJC {
    node [style="filled"];  
    label = "SJC";
    channel [shape=cylinder];
}

subgraph cluster_Fleet {
    node [style="filled"];
    App1 [shape=cylinder];
    App2 [shape=cylinder];
    App3 [shape=cylinder];
    label = "Fleet of machines";
    style="filled";
    color="lightgrey";
}

App1 -> channel [lhead=cluster_SJC, ltail=cluster_Fleet];
```

}

My "cylinders" render as boxes.  Never gotten the cylinder shape to work in graphviz 2.38.0.

The `cluster_` convention before the subgraph name is a `dot` language construct that is not supported by all engines. 
[image]

Comment: Cylinder is indeed a problem on graphviz 2.38 at least in my debian. You can get the bust version 2.40 what looks that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There were two errors:

1. As explained in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586857), the prefix "**cluster**" was missing in the name of subgraph.
2. The tail and head were reversed.